# how to fix package android.support.v4.app not exist in androidx projects?

Tags: java, android

I am developing on an app that uses the ActionBarSherlock library project, and the current project uses androidx dependences.

If Make Project will appear 
android.support.v4.app not exist error.
error: can't find symbol 
symbol: class FragmentActivity
error: package mFragments not exist
and so on...

My question is 
1.How to be compatible with the previous android.support package in androidx? 
2.How to migrate to androidx correctly which using the old android support library?

My build.gradle in module as follws:
1. build.gradle in Module:ActionBarSherlock which is a lib project of module `app`
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

2. build.gradle in `app` which using the above `ActionBarSherlock` as lib project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    compile project(':ActionBarSherlock')
    configurations.compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:library:4.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: why are you using actionbarsherlock in 2019? your minsdk is 15 and androidx support lib is more than capable to provide functionality down to that api level. you don't need actionbersherlock

Comment: Because I am doing some research and  development on a legacy project which used actionbarsherlock.

Comment: enable jetifier to convert the android.* dependencies from the libraries

Comment: Yes, I do .In gradle.properties , I set android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true.  I have already use the as  mirgate tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

> ActionBarSherlock is deprecated. No more development will be taking
>   place.

As it says in its [official repository](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

So I remind you not to use that library.

Comment: yes,I need to run this legacy project first which using the ActionBarSherlock, and then I would like to  find a way to replace  the ActionBarSherlock. Please tell me how to handle it.